# Text shuffle on reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="t1"></div>
<div id="t2"></div>
```

So in these two divs I want to rotate 4 lines of text...obviously the way I tried to set it up doesn't work, before t2 div just copies the t div...any ideas how to fix this? If there's another way I'm listening, I'm not to code savvy, more of copy paste tweak test type of coding...this is a simple game I'm trying to make on my website so I'm looking for solution...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var scn = new Array();
scn[0] = "red";
scn[1] = "blue";
scn[2] = "green";
scn[3] = "yellow";
var myRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*scn.length);
//$(document).ready(function() {
$('#t1').html(scn[myRandom]);
$('#t2').html(scn[myRandom]); 
//});
</script>
```

Comment: just generate your random number twise and set in diff divs.

Comment: I'm not positive what you're asking for:  do you want the two divs to each contain one of the strings you've got, randomly selected from the list, and not duplicate each other?  So given your array of four strings, the first div has any one of the four, and the second any one of the remaining three strings?

Comment: The second time maybe check that the number is different or you may end up with the same text sometimes

Comment: If you downvote people who are giving your help for free, they will be less likely to help at all. You could atleast give a comment as to what is wrong with a given answer.

Comment: I would like to make the div's rotate the text but never show the same text string at the same time...

Comment: @user1429247 that was not clear in your question. Also what do you mean by rotate? You would like them to be random but not the same? You would like them to update on page refresh or in real time, like every few seconds?

Comment: Update on user refresh, no real time refresh, strictly manual :)

Comment: @Fresheyeball That logic kind of suggests we should never downvote anything, because giving help for free to people with questions is kind of the point of SO/SE.  If an answer doesn't work or isn't good, downvotes are a necessary evil.  It doesn't look like the OP is the one downvoting, regardless.

Comment: @JimDagg I believe we should only be downvoting if we are willing to leave a comment, or upvote a comment. Downvoting without context is useless.

Comment: @Fresheyeball You are right, and that is why I commented on the downvote, it was not OP that downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding the problem statement correctly, what you have is calling for a basic variation of a shuffling algorithm.  You need two elements from a starting array, without replacement.

The most efficient shuffling algorithm out there is what's called a Fisher-Yates shuffle, which has a complexity of order-n -- that is, it'll take time and space roughly proportional to the number of elements you're working with.  How it works is it takes a random element in the array and swaps it with the first; then, it takes a random element in the array *after the first* and swaps it with the second; and so on.  You get a perfectly (pseudo-)randomized array, and it takes one logical operation for each element.

If you shuffle the array and then take the first two elements from it, you can present those in the two divs.

[Mike Bostocks](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/) has a good implementation of a Fisher-Yates shuffle:

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var m = array.length, t, i;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle…
  while (m) {

    // Pick a remaining element…
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

    // And swap it with the current element.
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }

  return array;
}
```

If we run your array `scn` through that, and then take the first two elements into the divs, you'll have what you're looking for.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var scn = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];  // or whatever array, doesn't matter
$(document).ready(function() {
  shuffle(scn);
  $('#t1').html(scn[0]);
  $('#t2').html(scn[1]); 
});

// insert shuffle function code here
</script>
```

The naive approach would be to just take a random number from 1-4 twice, make sure they're unequal, and pluck elements from the array that way, but if you're planning on using this code in a game, a shuffling algorithm is more scalable -- just adjust the size of the array and the divs you're inserting to and you can have a set of arbitrary size.

Comment: Tried it, and it works! I'm trying it with 4 divs and it always shuffles, never 2 of the same...thanks a bunch!

Comment: Great, glad to hear that!  When you find an answer you're satisfied with, go ahead and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

In a very simple way you can just remove the first selected element:

```
var scn = [];
scn[0] = "red";
scn[1] = "blue";
scn[2] = "green";
scn[3] = "yellow";
var myRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * scn.length);
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#t1').html(scn[myRandom]);
    scn.splice(myRandom, 1); // remove one element at "myRandom" index
    myRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * scn.length);
    $('#t2').html(scn[myRandom]);
});
```

Comment: If the requirement was there to never repeat, this is the way I would have done it, too. +1

Answer (score 0):

Nice and simple. [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FkLls)

```
var scn = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];

$(function() {
  var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * scn.length),
      rand2 = rand1 === scn.length-1 ? 0 : rand1 + 1;
  $('#t1').html(scn[rand1]);
  $('#t2').html(scn[rand2]);
});
```

The idea is that `rand2` will always be the 'next' value in the array after `rand1`

---

A bit more complex [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Caxiq)

```
var scn = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'],

getRand = function(check){
  var res = Math.floor(Math.random() * scn.length);
  if(res == check){ return getRand(check); }
  else{ return res; }  
};

$(function() {
  var rand1 = getRand(),
      rand2 = getRand(rand1);
  $('#t1').html(scn[rand1]);
  $('#t2').html(scn[rand2]);
});
```

We can use a recursive function to produce a second random number that is not the first.

Comment: This solution does produce a randomized result, but it's incomplete.  You only get as many permutations as the length of the array (in this case, four), and if you get the last one, the second div is empty.  I get one of either red/blue, blue/green, green/yellow, or yellow/blank.

Comment: um no. read it again, there will never be a blank

Comment: Respecfully, those were the results I got from repeated trials in the very same demo you linked to.  rand1 will only ever be in the set [0, scn.length - 1], which means your conditional will never be true.  If you replace scn.length in the ternary expression with (scn.length - 1), it'll get you what you're looking for (no blanks), but the value in the second div will still depend on the first.

Comment: @JimDagg you are correct, I was missing the `-1`. Answer and codepen updated

Comment: @JimDagg I have also now provided a second answer that is truly more random with a recursive function.

Answer (score -3):

`var getColor = function() {
  return scn[Math.floor(Math.random()*scn.length)]
}
$('#t1').html(getColor())
$('#t2').html(getColor())`

Comment: Because you may still get the same colour twice.